# 404 Page Not Found /opt/lampp/htdocs/testing

Tags: php, linux, api, xampp, centos7

I've installed XAMPP 8.0.1  on CentOS 7. I placed my work-folder `testing/` in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/testing/`. That directory contains my API.

When I `GET` data using Postman as the following URL

```
http://192.168.43.66:80/testing/testingapi/tests/action/log/limit/10/offset/0
```

I cannot get any data. Instead, it gives "404 Page Not Found":

[image]

But when I did the same thing on Windows 10, with the same version of XAMPP, it works:

[image]

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: hiiii! verify apache configuration?

Comment: apache is auto run, I can redirect "http://192.168.43.66:80", any need other configuration?

Comment: But check the httpd.conf configuration , if the path of the files are correct.
And you u

Comment: are you using some framework in PHP?

Comment: Yes, also path is correct. I don't know any framework because developer give me that folder,and he wanna use on linux.So I test on window-10, project is working, and finally I change to linux OS, then project is not working.